# Why is Inverse Permutation Used in Definition of Symmetric Product of 1-Linear Forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I am currently learning linear algebra on Brilliant (on the Tensor Products lesson), and I am confused about why the inverse permutation, instead of the regular permutation, is used to define the symmetric product of 1-linear forms.

The symmetric product $f_1 \odot \cdots \odot f_n$, where $f_i$ are 1-linear forms $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, creates a $n$-linear symmetric form $\underbrace{V\times\cdots\times V}_{n \ \textrm{times}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where switching any two input vectors does not change the output. The symmetric product uses the tensor product $\otimes$, which is defined as the following:

let $T$ be a $t$-linear form on vector space $V$ and $S$ be a $s$-linear form on vector space $W$ with the same scalars, then
$$(T \otimes S)(v_1,\ldots,v_t,w_1,\ldots,w_s)=T(v_1,\ldots,v_t)S(w_1,\ldots,w_s), \ v_i \in V, \ w_i \in W.$$

The symmetric product is defined as the following:

let $S_n$ be the set of every bijection of $\\{1,2,\ldots,n\\}$ (i.e., the set of permutations of $n$ items) and $\sigma$ be one such bijection in $S_n$; define

$$\sigma(f_1,\ldots,f_n)=[f_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes f_{\sigma(n)}]$$

and

$$f_1\odot\cdots\odot f_n=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\sigma^{-1}(f_1,\ldots,f_n).$$

---

**The $\sigma^{-1}$ in this definition is what trips me up.** I'm assuming $\sigma^{-1}$ means inverse permutation. As far as I can tell, $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ do the same thing; they create the same sum of tensor products in the symmetric product definition. Am I getting something wrong here? Does $\sigma^{-1}$ not actually mean the inverse permutation?

Comment: You are correct, in the expression you wrote $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ accomplish the same thing because we are summing over all permutations. Without more context I don't think anyone can say why someone would choose one over the other.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff
The symmetric product is being used to create a basis for the vector space of $n$-linear symmetric forms, if this provides any more context. More specifically, $\{f_{j_1}\odot\cdots\odot f_{j_n}\}$, where $f_i$ is from the dual basis of a vector space and $j_1\leq\cdots\leq j_n$, forms a basis for the space of $n$-linear symmetric forms.